# Increase /dev/shm in docker container in swarm environment (docker stack deploy)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, swarm

I know is possible to increase default 64MB /dev/shm in docker container from docker run or docker compose. As example this works in our local development machines.

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    shm_size: '1gb'
```

However when I try to do it in our swarm docker stack deploy stack_name -c docker-compose.yml I get a "Ignoring unsupported options: shm_size" and shm mount remains as default 64MB.

What can I do? I tried to create an image with this parameter but it seems is not something that I can add to image built, more like a runtime option. It's possible to modify it after container creation?

Environment is an Ubuntu 16.04 with docker 17.12 in a single node swarm.

Answer (score 15):

You can add the following code in docker-compose.yml. It will directly add a tmpfs volume targetting /dev/shm:

```
volumes:
      - type: tmpfs
        target: /dev/shm
        tmpfs:
           size: 4096000000 # (this means 4GB)
```

Comment: This seems to be the official workaround, thanks for the example!

Answer (score 6):

<strike>You need to use a more recent version of Docker Compose. The latest version (docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa5906) certainly supports it.</strike>

The above answer was assuming Docker Compose, but `docker swarm` is not the same thing at all. [`docker swarm` does not yet support `shm_size` in the configuration file](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26714), but does seem to have workarounds.

Comment: It still doesn't work with the latest version ( the one in your answer ). After running this command
`docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.swarm.yml my_stack`
I have the following warning:
`Ignoring unsupported options: shm_size`

Answer (score 3):

I found solution for docker swarm:

```
postgres:
  image: postgres:11-alpine
  shm_size: "512M"
  command: >
    postgres
    -c shared_preload_libraries='pg_stat_statements'
    -c pg_stat_statements.track=all
    -c max_connections=200
    -c shared_buffers=256MB
    -c statement_timeout=1800000
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
  environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: my_db
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123123
    POSTGRES_USER: my_user
    TZ: "Europe/Moscow"
  tmpfs:
    - /tmp:size=512M
  volumes:
  - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
  - type: tmpfs
    target: /dev/shm
  networks:
    - default
```

Comment: It worked for me, even though the line `shm_size` is ignored.